# Vagrant provision fail with puppet

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Hello i have generated a vm on http://vmg.slynett.com/.

The vm works fine but nothing is installed on it.
I don't know why vagrant provision fail.

```
vagrant provision
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::Shell...
stdin: is not a tty
Europe/Paris

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Paris'
Local time is now:      Fri Jun 28 13:15:42 CEST 2013.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Jun 28 11:15:42 UTC 2013.

[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::Puppet...
[default] Running Puppet with /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/base.pp...
stdin: is not a tty
Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
Warning: Config file /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml not found, using Hiera defaults
Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type concat at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apache/manifests/init.pp:130 on node dev
Error: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type concat at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0/apache/manifests/init.pp:130 on node dev
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

cd /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests && puppet apply --modulepath '/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/base.pp --detailed-exitcodes || [ $? -eq 2 ]
```

I am on mac OS X 10.8.3, virtualbox 4.2.6, Vagrant 1.2.2

Comment: What is in your file init.pp at line 130? More code would be helpful

Comment: init.pp : https://gist.github.com/shima5/5884040
Vagrantfile : https://gist.github.com/shima5/5884050

Comment: It has only 22 lines, where to look for line number 130?? :D

Comment: Its the first link https://gist.github.com/shima5/5884040

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to the concat module from [ripenaar/concat](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/ripienaar/concat) and an error like that is usually thrown when a resource isn't present (i.e. not installed or in your module path).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding the [`concat`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/concat) and [`file_concat`](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/electrical/file_concat) puppet modules to the puppet module path. I usually have all needed puppet modules as git submodules in `puppet/modules` of the vagrant project, so to add the `concat` and `file_concat` module, I do:

```
git submodule add https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-concat.git puppet/modules/concat
git submodule add https://github.com/electrical/puppet-lib-file_concat.git puppet/modules/file_concat
```

Note that the `concat` module is the official one from puppetlabs and the `file_concat` module is the one used in `concat` (it should be installed automatically, but this didn't seem to work for me and may be your problem as well).